# calculate based on multiple criteria across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet for data entry called 'Data'. Entered data are sex, age and a score. In another worksheet "FACTG_Ref" that works as a reference/lookup include sex, age1, age2, left and right. age1 and age2 works as range for age group. left and right work as range for score.

[image: Data]

[image: FACTG_Ref]

I need to calculate column "BELOW', "BETWEEN" and "ABOVE" in sheet 'Data', based on sex values in sheet 'Data' matching sex in 'FACTG_Ref', age values in the right age range (between age1 and age2 in FACTG_Ref). If age is under 18, leave all calculation blank. Then if score is below left, then BELOW = 1, score is between left and right, BETWEEN = 1, if score is above right, ABOVE = 1.

Comment: I think you can use `=SUMPRODUCT()` formulas in your below and above columns (2 separate formulas), then between column would be an '=IF()` statement to test if below or above was not zero.

Comment: can you write out the how `=SUMPRODUCT()` is used in this case? Thanks. I still don't know how

Comment: You have a female 15 year, but no data for that range of age.  what should be returned then?

Comment: @ScottCraner. leave blank. I edited my post. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will find the correct row and pass the two variables to the Match which then passes it to the outer INDEX to choose the correct value.

If this value matches the title a `1` is placed or `0` if not:

```
=IF(OR($K2<18,$J2="Missing"),"",--(M$1=IFERROR(INDEX({"BETWEEN","ABOVE"},MATCH($L2,INDEX($F:$G,MATCH($J2,$A:$A,0)+MATCH($K2,$B$2:$B$7)-1,0))),"BELOW")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*`COUNTIF` wrapped with `IF` can solve the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `D21`, fill it across.

  ```
  =IF(D$20="Below",IF($B21<18,"",COUNTIF($C21:$C21,"<"&Sheet2!$L21)),IF(D$20="Between",IF($B21<18,"",COUNTIFS($C21:$C21,">="&Sheet2!$L21,$C21:$C21,"<="&Sheet2!$M21)),IF(D$20="Above",IF($B21<18,"",COUNTIF($C21:$C21,">"&Sheet2!$M21)),0)))
  ```

*You may adjust Sheet Name & Cell references in the formula as needed.*