# calculate based on multiple criteria across multiple sheets/columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to fill columns "HRQOL_below", "HRQOL_above", "HRQOL_between" based on multiple criteria in multiple columns.

My data
[image: My data]

The rule is:

1) look at HRQOL_Name first. They can be "FACT G", "PROMIS" or "SWL"

2) if HRQOL_Name is "FACT G", the rule becomes and the post is answered [calculate based on multiple criteria across multiple columns](https://superuser.com/questions/1508011/calculate-based-on-multiple-criteria-across-multiple-columns)

3) if HRQOL_Name is "PROMIS",  when HRQOL_Score less than 45, below = 1, HRQOL_Score above 55, above = 1,  score between 45 and 55, between = 1

4) if HRQOL_Name is "SWL",  when score less than 20, below =1; score above 25, above = 1, score between 20 and 24, between = 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the problem?

Comment: Since already U have similar example available then what problem you are facing ? Please share what you have been tried so far, help us to fix it!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use an if statement with a combination of and/or statements. The formula below can be used to calculate the "HRQOL_above" column, you'll want to modify it for the above and between columns:

```
=IF(OR(AND(AW2="SWL",AX2>25),AND(AW2="PROMIS",AX2>55)),1,0)
```

Note: this only works for point 3 and 4 in your question above-- not sure I understand what you're looking at for point 2, but if you already have a formula that works you can just add it on to this.